# Comparing list to array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements that have different classes like this:

```
<div class="class-a class-b class-c class-d"></div>
<div class="class-a class-c"></div>
<div class="class-b class-c class-f"></div>
so on and so forth
```

I also have an array like this:

```
classArray = ["class-a", "class-b", "class-f"]
```

What I would like to do is loop through and hide the divs that don't have classes listed in the array. I have this code that sort of works if there's only one class in the array, but if I add more, it only finds the last one and uses that.

```
for(var i = 0, c = classArray.length; i < c; i++) {
            $lesson.each(function() {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('' + classArray[i] + '')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What are the filtering rules? First div has 2 of the classes but not the third for example ... match any or match all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array as a selector by joining the classes together

```js
var classArray = ["class-a", "class-b", "class-f"];

$('div').removeClass('active')
        .filter('.' + classArray.join(', .'))
        .addClass('active')
```

```css
.active {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-a class-b class-c class-d">1</div>
<div class="class-a class-c">2</div>
<div class="class-b class-c class-f">3</div>
<div class="class-e">4</div>
```

Another way would be to use `toggleClass` in a loop or with a callback, something like

```
$('div').each( (_, el) => {
    $(el).toggleClass('active', $(el).is('.' + classArray.join(', .')));
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think you have the class applications reversed... OP wants "active" only on elements that match the class list

Comment: @MattDiamond - looks like you're right. It's just a replacement of `not` with `filter`